# select all fields of rows and group them based on one column

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

The table in database has column a,b,c .each two rows in database have same values in column c . I want to get and store these pairs for the next operations.
I am using hibernate (But not criteria interface).
What is the best solution?

Person Entity:

```
+--------------+----+-------+---+
| person Object| a  |b      | c |
+--------------+----+-------+---+
|     p1       |  w | d     |  1 |
|     p2       |  d | d     |  2 |
|     p3       |  f | e     |  3 |
|     p4       |  x | f     |  1 |
|     p5       |  w | g     |  2 |
|     p6       |  g | s     |  3 |
|     p7       |  x | h     |null|
|     p8       |  q | null  |  4 |
|     p9       |  w | null  |null|
```

expected output :
A list of pairs row with same "C" :[{p1,p4} ,{p2,p5} ,{p3,p6}]

p1 is retrieved hibernate object from entity not a string or a column . p1 is object of first row. I want to get pair of hibernate objects, pair of rows.

Comment: your question is not clear , give some example with data and what output is needed.

Comment: @Ramki I edited my post . Thank's

Comment: you can try LISTAGG ()  this will give multiple 
row values int single column search some example in internet https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php

Comment: @Ramki p1 is retrieved hibernate object from entity not a string or a column . p1 is object of first row. I want to get pair of hibernate objects, pair of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with data (rn, person, a, b, c) as
 (
   select rownum rn, t.* from 
   (
    select     'p1',         'w' , 'd'     ,  1 from dual union all 
    select     'p2',         'd' , 'd'     ,  2 from dual union all 
    select     'p3',         'f' , 'e'     ,  3 from dual union all 
    select     'p4',         'x' , 'f'     ,  1 from dual union all 
    select     'p5',         'w' , 'g'     ,  2 from dual union all 
    select     'p6',         'g' , 's'     ,  3 from dual union all 
    select     'p7',         'x' , 'h'     ,  null from dual union all
    select     'p8',         'q' , null    ,  4 from dual union all 
    select     'p9',         'w' , null    ,  null from dual
   ) t
)
,
cte (rn, person, a, b, c, pair) as
(
  select rn, person, a, b, c, null from data
  union all
  select data.rn, null, null, null, null,  '{' ||  cte.person || ',' || data.person || '}' from cte join data on (cte.c = data.c and cte.rn < data.rn)
)
select 
  '"C":' || 
  '[' || listagg(pair, ',')  within group(order by rn) || ']' result 
from cte 
where pair is not null;
```

Comment: sorry..I think my input was not clear...I assumed p1 as retrieved hibernate object from entity not a string and a column . p1 is object of first row